# How to post process a thresholded binary image to extract the exact no. of pixels

Tags: image, medical

I have a medical binary image that I got after manually thresholding a grayscale medical image.during thresholding , I noticed some overlapped regions in histogram  that contained pixels which could be of any type( either glandulat tissue type- I considered these in above threshold range , or fat tissue-I considered these in below threshold range)
How can I post process the binary image to get exact no. of pixels of glandular tissue only, discarding the effect of wrongly thresholded pixels in overlapped region? please help

Answer (score 0):

There is no difficulty maintaining one counter per pixel type and incrementing every time you classify a pixel.

If you have more than two classes, obviously a binary image cannot store this information and you need to count before binarization.